# Powershell Get-Process behavior - Can't find process under certain conditions

Tags: powershell, process, sccm

I am working on a powershell script that looks for a defined process in order to stop it (and restart it, if it was running before) in order to perform an update of that software.

We use the `Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager` to perform that task.

Running the Powershell directly with user rights with the user accounts, finds the process.
Running the Powershell directly script with admin rights with the user account finds the porcess.
Running the Powershell via SCCM with user rights with the user accounts, does NOT find the process.

Here is a snippet that we use for debugging:

```
$fileName = "MyFile.exe"
$processes = Get-Process

foreach ($process in $processes) {
    
    # Process found?
    if ($process.MainModule.FileName -like "*\$fileName") {
        Write-Host "Process found" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Not the right process" $process.MainModule.FileName -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Normally, only differences in the ability to access _properties_ of the process-info objects reported are to be expected. Is there something special about the process in question? Does the problem also occur with other tools, such as `tasklist.exe`? Can you verify independently whether the process actually exists? As an aside: `$fileName = 'MyFile'; Get-Process -Name $fileName` should normally do. That is, the `.Name` property is the executable file name without its extension.

Comment: IIRC, SCCM is a 32-bit process, which may likely be invoking 32-bit PowerShell, and when evaluating the **MainModule** property, may only be reporting 32-bit processes.  As such, is the process you are looking for 64-bit?  If so, this may explain why it's missing.  Try forcing SCCM to use: %SystemRoot%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Answer (score 1):

Based on @mklement0 I created a *workaround*:

```
$taskListOutput = & tasklist /fo csv /FI "imagename eq $fileName"

$splitTaskListOutput = $taskListOutput -split "`r`n"
if($splitTaskListOutput.Count -gt 1)
{
    Write-Host "Process found"
     try {      
        $columns = $splitTaskListOutput[1].Trim('"') -split '","'
        # Stop by process ID
        Stop-Process -Id $columns[1]
        Write-Host "Process terminated"
     } catch {
        return -1 # Process could not be terminated
    }
}
```

The actual reason why the process can not be found in powershell by SCCM remains a mystery.

Comment: Nice; would indeed be good to know the cause. Note that PowerShell always collects output from external programs _as individual lines_, so there is no need for ``-split "`r`n"`` (which therefore has no effect).

Comment: Note that you can simplify your solution as follows: `& tasklist /fo csv /FI "imagename eq $fileName" | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object { "Process found with PID: " + $_.PID; <# ... #> }`